# What type of Keyframe this is? And how to add it

Tags: keyframes

Its a lot smaller than the usual keyframes, about the size of a "litter" keyframe but that's not it either.

[image]

If you want to view the model/animation itself here it is:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kuELxipaR78U3wjS8rTXJyWgtV0aUSxh/view?usp=sharing

Comment: what method did you use to make the cube move?